# Android WeakReference to handle memory leakage

Tags: android, weak-references

Please check the below code,
Can we use the WeakReferences like below in Utils class to handle context memory leakage?

```
private static final String TAG = "Utils";
private static Utils instance;
private Context context;

public Utils(WeakReference<Context> context) {
    this.context = context.get();
}

public static synchronized final Utils getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Utils(new WeakReference<Context>(context));
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: If you want to keep a ref to a Context use `context.getApplicationContext()`. This would not create a memory leak as long as the application is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a WeakReference can return null at any time so it makes this kind of pointless.

You are going to have check the WeakReference for a null every time you access it and then you will need to deal with that case by providing the context in the methods arguments, therefore eliminating the need to store a context in the fields.

A better (but not the best) solution is to use the ApplicationContext, `context.getApplicationContext()`, probably the best is to pass the context into every method call.

Answer (score 0):

`private WeakReference<Context> context;`

in constructor: (make it private if you are trying to make singleton class)

`this.context = context;`

everything else is looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to check for memory leaks. It does the same thing but with just one line of code. It will tell you the root of every memory leak.

Comment: Using that tool i got to know that my Utils class leaking memory of 3 MB. So i am looking to fix the issue.

Comment: Remember not to declare `Context` as `static` anywhere or any `Class` which takes a `Context` in it's constructor as `static`.